# Reputation change -2, -1, -2, -2 on user account removal

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, deleted-accounts

Tonight I got the following reputation change notification:

[image]

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311413/2947502) it must have happened because a user account which was used to accept my edits got removed.

Important fact: I still have <2000 reputation on AskUbuntu and I reached 1000 rep point limit from suggested edits some time ago. My [reputation page](https://askubuntu.com/reputation) shows `earned 1000 reputation from suggested edits`.

That means if reputation change from "user was removed"-event was from the reputation gained with edits, my reputation from suggested edits should decrease below 1000 and I should be able to regain it my making another approved edit (just like happened several times with deleted questions). I [tried](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/581224) and it did not happen, meaning my reputation from edits is still at constant 1000.

So either:

- <strike>the 1000 reputation limit from suggested edits is not really set on reputation points, but on the number of 500 edits</strike> which can easily be ruled out, because users can gain multiple +2s from editing one post or gain no reputation from editing posts after the daily was cap reached, yet reputation limit seems to be properly implemented at 1000 points;

or

- the reputation change from "user was removed"-event was implemented not as history rewrite (like in case of deleted questions), but by adding negative reputation (hence visible in reputation history)ーhowever it decreases only overall reputation, and does not decrease the reputation-from-suggested-edits counter  (the one checked against the 1000-point limit)ーthis sounds like a bug (it should work in the same way as with deleted questions);

or

- -2, -1<sup>*</sup>, -2, -2 reputation change from "user was removed"-event was not really from reverting the editsーthen from what?

Which is true? Or is there any logical explanation to this?

---

<sup>*</sup> Because of a daily cap, one of my edits gave me +1 reputation.

Comment: Is [this explanation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311413/2947502) wrong?

Comment: hmm... I read your question, but not that answer you linked to, sorry about that. The reputation loss when the final approver is deleted is new to me, but being posted by SE employee it's correct.

Comment: You tried... Wait? The edit you linked was approved by a user who is already deleted, you should try again.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/580995) edit, which you have linked, was approved by a user who is already deleted. This means you haven't got the rep again (you actually did, then the user got removed, and then you saw the reputation hasn't changed).

Comment: This is absolutely ridiculous,  I have no idea why you're so lucky :D

Comment: Another [approved edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/581224) no reputation gained.

Comment: @PythonMaster The editing privilege is at 2000. Sorry, but you are mixing up two separate things. Please read my question before claiming I am incorrect.

Comment: If you try reputation audit on that site (i.e http://askubuntu.com/reputation), at the bottom of the page is the rep you've gained from suggested edits. Is it still capped at 1000 already?

Comment: @meatball Yes, it is. Thank you for showing me another method instead of checking subsequent edit. That's the point of my question: if a question that I got +2 from editing gets deleted, this goes down below 1000; now (assuming it was the real reason) if user account was deleted, the rep from edits remain constant although total rep decreases.

Comment: +1 (+100 if I could)

Comment: @Asadefa: No, since the proposed dupe target is clear that some accounts will still have all their votes wiped (and in practice this is fairly common), so this bug will still show up in such cases.